# CASE/EXISTS IN WHERE Clause in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have a query that I need to add condition in WHERE Clause. The condition is if companyID is within the certain list then only show users that has LocationTypeID else show all users. Is there anyway to achieve this?

```
SELECT 
    UserID
FROM [Account].[User] AS [User]
INNER JOIN [Account].[Location] as [Location]
    ON [Location].[LocationID] = [User].[LocationID]
```

I am trying to add condition in where clause, but not sure how to do it.

```
WHERE
CASE WHEN Location.CompanyID IN (123, 344, 444, 565)
THEN 'AND Location.LocationTypeID IS NOT NULL'
```

Comment: It's generally better to use AND/OR constructions instead of case expressions in the WHERE clause.'

Comment: But this may not return the results the OP wants. It looks like they want all companies but when the company id is in the specified list they also want to check if the location type is not null. Making this an AND in the where clause will just exclude any rows that aren't in the list of company ids. Can you clarify what your result set should look like?

Comment: `if A then B` is close to `A implies B`, which is `(not A) or B`. So `WHERE Location.CompanyID NOT IN (123, 344, 444, 565) OR Location.LocationTypeID IS NOT NULL` might be what you're after (the question's a little unclear). This may need more polishing if `CompanyID` could be `NULL`, since `NOT IN` doesn't play nice with that.

Comment: @charleh - Yes,  I updated my description. Sorry, it got posted without correct description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People always seem to want to use `CASE` when simple logical combinations will work:

```
WHERE
Location.CompanyID NOT IN (123, 344, 444, 565)
OR Location.LocationTypeID IS NOT NULL
```

Note that I've inverted the first condition so we only need the second condition to be true if the first turns out to be false. Of course, they may both be true but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: You may have to add `OR Location.CompanyID IS NULL` in case the column  is nullable.

Answer (score 2):

use you condition like below

```
SELECT 
    UserID
FROM [Account].[User] AS [User]
INNER JOIN [Account].[Location] as [Location]
    ON [Location].[LocationID] = [User].[LocationID] 
    where        
    (
     Location.CompanyID IN (123, 344, 444, 565)
     AND Location.LocationTypeID IS NOT NULL
    ) 
     OR 
     (
      Location.CompanyID not IN (123, 344, 444, 565)          
     )
```

Comment: Sorry, updated my description, I want that if company id is not in above list, then show all users. Only add 'AND' condition if companyID is within that list.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query -:

```
SELECT 
    UserID
FROM [Account].[User] AS [User]
INNER JOIN [Account].[Location] as [Location]
    ON [Location].[LocationID] = [User].[LocationID]
WHERE
Location.CompanyID IN (123, 344, 444, 565)
AND Location.LocationTypeID IS NOT NULL
```

SQL server 2014

Comment: This is give me 0 users when companyID is not in the list. I need all users if companyID not in the list.